# ZFS volume is not accessible

Tags: virtualization, freebsd, vmware-vsphere, zfs, truenas

I'm using FreeNAS-11.2-U4.1. The server is used for storing VMWare vSphere virtual machines. There are two zvols: Lab and Edari. Both of them belong to the same pool, SSD-Storage.

The problem is that vSphere can't mount one of the zvols, Edari. So the virtual machines stored in this pool are inaccessible. But the other is fine and I can browse its files.

I get this alert on the web interface of FreeNAS (which I'm not sure if it is related to the problem, because the zvol Edari doesn't belong to it):

```
The volume Pool-1.8SSD state is UNKNOWN: Wed, 14 Aug 2019 05:59:38 GMT
```

But zpool status says nothing about this pool:

```
root@Storage[~]# zpool status
  pool: SSD-Storage
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 0 days 00:48:30 with 0 errors on Wed Aug 14 12:50:59 2019
config:

    NAME                                            STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    SSD-Storage                                     ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-0                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/ec475918-925c-11e9-af9b-f4ce46a6411d  ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/f1ed0bd1-925c-11e9-af9b-f4ce46a6411d  ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/f796acd9-925c-11e9-af9b-f4ce46a6411d  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

  pool: freenas-boot
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 0 days 00:00:05 with 0 errors on Wed Aug  7 03:45:05 2019
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    freenas-boot  ONLINE       0     0     0
      da0p2     ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

And this is what happens when I try to import the pools:

```
root@Storage[~]# zpool import
root@Storage[~]#
```

This pool is not even listed here. How could ZFS completely forget about a pool, such that it never existed? I searched through forums an I found out that this may be due to using RAID, but I don't use RAID. This is what gpart shows:

```
root@Storage[~]# gpart show
=>       40  488326960  da0  GPT  (233G)
     40       1024    1  freebsd-boot  (512K)
       1064  488308736    2  freebsd-zfs  (233G)
  488309800      17200       - free -  (8.4M)

=>        40  1953459552  da1  GPT  (931G)
      40          88       - free -  (44K)
     128     4194304    1  freebsd-swap  (2.0G)
     4194432  1949265160    2  freebsd-zfs  (929G)

=>        40  1953459552  da2  GPT  (931G)
      40          88       - free -  (44K)
     128     4194304    1  freebsd-swap  (2.0G)
     4194432  1949265160    2  freebsd-zfs  (929G)

=>        40  1953459552  da3  GPT  (931G)
      40          88       - free -  (44K)
     128     4194304    1  freebsd-swap  (2.0G)
     4194432  1949265160    2  freebsd-zfs  (929G)
```

And I found this on /var/logs/debug.log:

```
Aug 14 12:40:19 Storage uwsgi: [storage.models:123] Exception on retrieving disks for Pool-1.8SSD: list index out of range
```

This is the output of zfs list:

```
root@Storage[~]# zfs list
NAME                                USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
SSD-Storage                        1.76T  88.0G   117K  /mnt/SSD-Storage
SSD-Storage/Cload                  60.9G   149G  74.6K  -
SSD-Storage/Edari                   660G   571G   178G  -
SSD-Storage/Lab                    1.04T   923G   232G  -
SSD-Storage/iocage                  858K  88.0G   155K  /mnt/SSD-Storage/iocage
SSD-Storage/iocage/download         117K  88.0G   117K  /mnt/SSD-Storage/iocage/download
SSD-Storage/iocage/images           117K  88.0G   117K  /mnt/SSD-Storage/iocage/images
SSD-Storage/iocage/jails            117K  88.0G   117K  /mnt/SSD-Storage/iocage/jails
SSD-Storage/iocage/log              117K  88.0G   117K  /mnt/SSD-Storage/iocage/log
SSD-Storage/iocage/releases         117K  88.0G   117K  /mnt/SSD-Storage/iocage/releases
SSD-Storage/iocage/templates        117K  88.0G   117K  /mnt/SSD-Storage/iocage/templates
freenas-boot                        760M   224G    64K  none
freenas-boot/ROOT                   760M   224G    29K  none
freenas-boot/ROOT/Initial-Install     1K   224G   756M  legacy
freenas-boot/ROOT/default           760M   224G   756M  legacy
```

One last thing is that, I frequently find this line in my /var/log/messages:

```
ctld: connect(2) failed for 172.19.20.11: Connection refused
```

172.19.20.11 is my FreeNAS server.

Could you help me to find out what's wrong with the zvol Edari?

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing what your problem is. The `SSD-Storage` pool is already imported, which is why it doesn't show up in the output of a bare `zpool import` (which lists importable, not-imported pools). Your `zfs list` output clearly shows both `SSD-Storage/Lab` and `SSD-Storage/Edari` as being there and having data. I don't see anything in your question that indicates a problem with that particular dataset. You say that you can't "mount" it, but don't show how you're doing it or what happens when you try, and one doesn't mount a zvol anyway, only the file system on it. Please clarify.